# DB2 SQL - Cannot successfully insert into table after trigger has been made

Tags: sql, db2

I have been running into problems inserting values into a table after having a trigger attached to it.
The trigger is the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig
AFTER INSERT ON Follows
REFERENCING NEW as N
FOR EACH row
WHEN ((Select email from Celebrity) <> N.followed_email)
UPDATE followSuggestion SET followSuggestion.Suggested_follower = N.followed_email, followSuggestion.Suggested_followee = N.follower_email
;
```

the insert code is the following:

```
INSERT INTO follows
VALUES('Michael_Phelps@uss.net','Michael_Phelps@uss.net');
```

And the error is as follows

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0811N  The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES 
INTO statement is more than one row.  SQLSTATE=21000

SQL0811N  The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the problem:

```
 (Select email from Celebrity) <> N.followed_email
```

The subquery will probably return more than one row so the scalar operator <> will not work. 
You will have to rephrase that condition to something like:

```
WHEN ((Select COUNT(email) from Celebrity WHERE email = N.followed_email) = 0) ...
```

Comment: Very good point, thank you very much for the concise and clear answer!